# How to delete a contact detail?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm trying to delete a detail from a contact in android.
For example a contact has an email and a phone number, let's say I want to delete just the phone number.
Assume that I already have the ID of the detail from a previous query.

My searches only found topics related to deleting the whole contact, which worked for me already.
This is about deleting a detail only, i.e. from the *ContactsContract.Data* table.

The relevant part from my code is pasted below, again the ID is already known.
The Log message reports that 1 entry has been deleted successfully, which is what I expected.
But when I switch to the Contacts app, the detail is still there. Even after restarting that app from scratch.
So something still doesn't seem to be updated correctly.

thanks for any help

```
private void deleteDetail(ContactDetail detail) {
    Uri detailsUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

    String selection = ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(detail.getID()) };

    int result = 0;
    try {
        result = mProvider.delete(detailsUri, selection, selectionArgs);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "deleteDetail() - id=" + detail.getID() + ", deleted "+result+" entries");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok, what might explain this is the existence of more then one occurrence of that phone in that contact's details.

For example, if you have `Whatsapp`, `Viber` or any other phone-based messaging app, they'll add a `RawContact` to each contact that has a phone number with duplicate phone number data row, and some other app-specific details.

This may be caused by any `RawContact` joined to that `Contact` that contains that phone you're trying to delete.

If you really want to permanently delete a detail, you could do something like this:

```
private void deleteDetail(long contactId, String phoneNumber) {
    Uri dataUri = Data.CONTENT_URI;

    String selection = Data.CONTACT_ID + " =? AND " + CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(contactId), phoneNumber };

    try {
        int result = mProvider.delete(dataUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "deleteDetail() - deleted: " + result + " entries");
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note that this will do exact phone compare, so if you have two phones saved for that contact, with different formats (dashes, country-code, etc.) it won't match all.
If you're targeting Android Jelly Beans and above, you can use [CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html#NORMALIZED_NUMBER) and compare it to the E164 format of the requested phone number (see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#formatNumberToE164(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)))

Comment: I don't believe this is the case here, for 2 reasons:

a) I'm running in an emulator and there are no other contact types I'm using, there are only the contacts I'm creating for these tests, mostly by code

b) similar to your suggestion I tried to delete with the following code:
Changing the selection such that it deletes *all* phone details of all contacts
     String selection = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
     String[] selectionArgs =  {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };

Comment: if you query for that contact's phone numbers after deleting them, are you getting back that deleted phone again?

Comment: strangely - no. the database seems correct from a program point of view. puzzled...

Comment: ugh - I finally traced down the problem to be my own mistake somewhere else in the code: the above code does work as designed!
The code is part of a regression test of my sync adapter, which erroneously recreated the detail again and again after deletion. So, checking the database by code results in what I expected, checking for it manually in the contacts app the syncadapter was quick enough to recreate it. 
I'm going to close this one as user error